# Datapager reverts back to original data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I made a search page linked to a database, when the page loads I use VB Codebehind to set the `SqlSelectCommand` for the `ListView` so it returns 0 results, when a client the searches for a item I change the Sql select to `LIKE '%search%'` .

This all works fine but what happens is that when you click on page 2 it reverts back to the original sql statement

I am using a `Label` for a heading which I also dynamically change according to the search key to make sure the data is returned to the page

You can Preview my site here
http://www.barkingdog.co.za/asp/Search1.aspx

The same problem On the Office page, here though I start the page with data in the sql select but when I click on eg. economy and then try to go to page 2 it shows page 2 of the original content

Thank you in advance

**The VB**

```
Protected Sub SearchBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBox.TextChanged
    Dim nval As String
    nval = Searchbox.Text
    BreadCrumb.Text = "Results for " + nval

    AllProductsOff.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [cxpproducts] WHERE [Range]  LIKE '%" & nval & "%'"
End Sub

Protected Sub SearchButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click
    Dim nval As String
    nval = Searchbox.Text
    BreadCrumb.Text = "Results for " + nval

    AllProductsOff.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [cxpproducts] WHERE [Range]  LIKE '%" & nval & "%'"
End Sub
```

**The ASP**

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" 
    Text="Search" PostBackUrl="./Search1.aspx" style="margin-top: 0px" />
```

**List View**

```
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <div style="" align="center">
     <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager2" runat="server">
       <Fields>
         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                        ShowNextPageButton="True" ShowPreviousPageButton="True" NextPageText=">>" LastPageText="Last" PreviousPageText="<<" />
         <asp:NumericPagerField />
         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
                        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
       </Fields>
     </asp:DataPager>
   </div>
   <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" class="style25">
     <span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
   </div>
   <div style="" align="center">
     <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server">
       <Fields>
         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
                        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" NextPageText=">>" PreviousPageText="<<" />
         <asp:NumericPagerField />
       </Fields>
     </asp:DataPager>
   </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing that problem in you listview paging. Please check the query which you are using when rebinding the listview on PagePropertiesChanging event as follow.

```
protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    //set current page startindex, max rows and rebind to false
    lvDataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);

    //rebind List View
    BindListView();
}
```

Please find more details about paging in Listview at following link.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/paging-listview-using